# Why is my $scope not working?

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie in angularJS. I have finished [phone-cat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on the official angular document. I am trying to create some new feature for it such as ( create a new item , edit ... ) Assume that I created api for this.

**app/phone-create/phone-create.module.js**

```
angular.module('phoneCreate', ['core.phone'])
```

**app/phone-create/phone-create.component.js**

```
angular.module('phoneCreate')
    .component('phoneCreate', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-create/phone-create.template.html',
        controller: ['Phone', '$scope',
            function PhoneCreateController(Phone, $scope) {
                var self = this;

                var data = {
                    name: $scope.name,
                    description: $scope.description,
                    kind: $scope.kind
                }

                self.create = function () {
                    console.log(data); // {name : underfined , desciprion : underfined , kind : underfined}
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

**app/phone-create/phone-create.template.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="description">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="kind">Kind</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.kind" class="form-control" id="kind" placeholder="Kind">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="$ctrl.create()" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click `Create` , I want to fields in input will be accessed by scope in controller but it is underfined. I don't know why and how to fix. Please help me!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at these three lines:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">

<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">

<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.kind" class="form-control" id="kind" placeholder="Kind">
```

They have ng-models: `$ctrl.name`, `$ctrl.description`, `$ctrl.kind`. Your component doesn't declare those variables.

Change them to `$ctrl.data.name`, `$ctrl.data.description`, `$ctrl.data.kind` and modify your component:

```
angular.module('phoneCreate')
.component('phoneCreate', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-create/phone-create.template.html',
    controller: ['Phone', '$scope',
        function PhoneCreateController(Phone, $scope) {
            var self = this;

            self.data = {
                name: "",
                description: "",
                kind: ""
            };

            self.create = function () {
                console.log(self.data);
            };
        }

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OPTION 1 :

```
angular.module('phoneCreate')
    .component('phoneCreate', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-create/phone-create.template.html',
        controller: ['Phone', '$scope',
            function PhoneCreateController(Phone, $scope) {
                var self = this;

                self.create = function () {
                    console.log(self.name); // {name : underfined , desciprion : underfined , kind : underfined}
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

OPTION 2 :

```
angular.module('phoneCreate')
    .component('phoneCreate', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-create/phone-create.template.html',
        controller: ['Phone', '$scope',
            function PhoneCreateController(Phone, $scope) {
                var self = this;

                // No need to initialise self.data
                self.data = {
                    name: '',
                    description: '',
                    kind: ''
                }

                self.create = function () {
                    console.log(self.data);
                    console.log(self.data.name);
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.data.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="description">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.data.description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="kind">Kind</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.data.kind" class="form-control" id="kind" placeholder="Kind">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="$ctrl.create()" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```